# container-fluid doesn't take full width except for navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```css
.container-fluid-1 {
padding: 0;

}


.navbar {
  padding: 0 5%;

}

.navbar-section{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1%;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
}

.nav-link:focus {
  color: black;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #feb633;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family: 'Hind Siliguri', sans-serif;
  color: #feb633;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: grey;
}

/* title */
.introduction {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: grey;
}

.twotitle {
  padding-top: 220px;
  padding-left: 200px;
}



.btn {
  background: #feb633;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #feb633;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in all;
  color: #feb633;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
```

I put a `container-fluid` class in my whole body but it doesn't provides a full width container except for navbar.
Everything looks fine on PC (1440px) but on mobile the whole body (except for navbar)moving to left side.

[Here is the screenshot on laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MVFO.png) that's what I want.

[Here is the screenshot on iPhoneX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOEKo.png) The grey background is on the left now.

Could someone please help me with it? Thanks in advance.

*container-fluid-1 is a class for CSS.

```html
<body>

  <!--navbar -->
  <div class="container-fluid-1 container-fluid">
    <section id="title">

      <div class="navbar-section">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class=" navbar-brand" href="#">M</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#title">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#services">Service</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#mini-shop">Mini Shop</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#contact-me">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>

      <!--title -->
      <div class="introduction row">
        <div class="twotitle col-lg-6">
          <h1>I'm Marcus</h1>
          <p class="subtitle">Web Design& Front End Developer</p>
          <br>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-6 col-md-6">Hire me</a>

        </div>

        <div class="profile col-lg-6">
          <img src="images/fa0b3895-7e4e-4ac9-a977-1a99fdefc4dd.png" alt="profile">
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Zim, it's for css!

Comment: You keep posting this question... Recently you give a link to your GitHub hosted website and then delete it. Please stop spamming the community.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```html
    <body>

  <!--navbar -->
  <div class="container-fluid-1 container-fluid">
    <section id="title">

      <div class="navbar-section">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class=" navbar-brand" href="#">M</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#title">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#services">Service</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#mini-shop">Mini Shop</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#contact-me">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>

      <!--title -->
      <div class="introduction row">
       <!--use mobile responsive classes here for full width use col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 -->
 <div class="twotitle col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h1>I'm Marcus</h1>
          <p class="subtitle">Web Design& Front End Developer</p>
          <br>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-6 col-md-6">Hire me</a>

        </div>

        <div class="profile col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <img src="images/fa0b3895-7e4e-4ac9-a977-1a99fdefc4dd.png" alt="profile">
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```